# enter one character in worksheet with having to confirm (return/enter)

Tags: excel, vba, events, enter, confirm

I have a worksheet in which users have to enter one character in a cell and I would like the cell to accept the new value without having to press RETURN (or ENTER) and stay in the same cell.

[enter status in one cell without confirmation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Uov.png)

How can I achieve this?

Grtz BartH

Comment: How can I achieve this? 1. Track Sheet Change event. 2. Once on desired cell, track key press on Excel (WinAPI is the only way). 3. Or Else super impose a textbox over the cell and track the keypress on the textbox.

Comment: How is `10` going to be entered as a single character??

Comment: You are right, YowE3K ;-) this should be 0-9

Answer (score 0):

OK, 
Looking for WinAPI I figuered out a suitable solution:

In Workbook_Open and Sheet_Activate I used the Application.OnKey procedure to trap my keys, like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     Application.OnKey ("1"), "testOne"
     'Here other keys
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
     Application.OnKey ("1"), "testOne"
     'Here other keys
End Sub
```

while the following procedure(s) in a standard Module take care of what I needed:

```
Sub testOne()
    ActiveCell.Value = 1
End Sub
'And Sub testTwo() etc.
```

(I don't need to bother to allow entering values in the other cells as they are locked anyway.)

Make sure you put the release of OnKey in Workbook_BeforeClose and Sheet_Deactive:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
     Application.OnKey ("1")
     'Here other keys
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
     Application.OnKey ("1")
     'Here other keys
End Sub
```

Maybe not the most advanced solution, but it works for what I need.

Grtz BartH